# How to use vertical-align: middle; properly in my code (or find a better solution for this without using position:absolute)

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```
<div class="container"> 
            <div class="text floatLeft">
                <h1> <span class="babyblue">App Store</span> Optimization</h1>
                <p>Over 60% of all app downloads come from search and the average app barel scratches the surface of this explosive channek. Can your app be found? </p>
            </div>
            <img src="http://example.com/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/images/OPTIMIZATION.png" class="floatRight">
        </div>
```

I have been trying to vertically align the 'text' class, but no success.

I tried using `display: table;` on the parent (.container) and `display: table-cell` on the text class, and nothing happens. I don't know if it's because I'm using 5, vh, vw instead of px.. anyway I need to center the text class vertically.

I tried using `position: relative` with `top: 50%` and I got no changes.

Is there any way to do this without the `position: absolute` property?

My current CSS:

```
.part2 {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #fff;
position: relative;
padding-top: 15%;
display: table;
}

.part2 .container {
width: 70%;
margin: 0 auto;
/* height: 40%; */
display: table;
margin-bottom: 7vh;
}

.part2 .text {
}
```

jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/jzhprfc4/

Comment: Updated it, Not much complex in my css it's a simple standard example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a solution

```css
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

.floatLeft {
    float: left;
}

.floatRight {
    float:right;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
}

.text {
    display: table-cell;
    background: yellow;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container cf"> 
            <div class="text ">
                <h1> <span class="babyblue">App Store</span> Optimization</h1>
                <p>Over 60% of all app downloads come from search and the average app barel scratches the surface of this explosive channek. Can your app be found? </p>
            </div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" class="floatRight">
  </div>
```

Comment: Please take look now http://jsfiddle.net/igorko82/16Lasky5/

You need to clearfix the container and remove float on .text element.

Comment: Looks really good, the only thing is that i have a margin-right for no reason, although margin=0. When I get the texts div smaller the margin decreases. how can i solve this? http://i.stack.imgur.com/WufYK.png

Comment: check styles for <p> maybe it has some width or margin in "%"

Comment: I just added a new class with float: right only for the images. Thank you ! You helped me A LOT !

Answer (score 0):

Here i update your **CSS:**

```
.text {
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
}

.container{
    clear:both;
    height:900px;
}
```

Check also: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ketan156/7yzdmLb1/)

Comment: I see it working but it's not working on my code for some reason. I thinks it's the "relative" part in the .text - Do you know maybe why?

Comment: You didn't give height of parent container. Just check it's height

Comment: I did, But it didn't center. 
and the height is with '%' and not px.

Comment: But. you post your css here. there is no any height given. check height with your firebug.

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot i unmarked it. 
I don't use height because it can be flexible. 
I am using wordpress so people can edit the texts and it can have a lot of content or a small amount of content.. so it has to be flexible. I cant use heights in this div (btw thanks for your attention :D)

Comment: Yes then how it can be vertically middle. if it's parent does not have much height. then give min-height to it's parent.

Comment: hey @Hatul you cant use vertival align without any height

Comment: Is there any way to center this maybe without vertical-align ?
I can send you the url if you want. email me walid.doch@gmail.com

Comment: using JQuery you can do it. Or position:absolute;

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .text {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border:1px solid #000;
    
    
   
}
 .text img{
     width:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    height:200px;
}
 

.container{
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:100%;
    display:table;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
            <div class="text">
                
                <h1> <span class="babyblue">App Store</span> Optimization</h1>
                <p>Over 60% of all app downloads come from search and the average app barel scratches the surface of this explosive channek. Can your app be found? </p>
            </div>
    <div class="text">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350g" alt="this is image" class="">
        </div>
    </div>
            
        </div>
```